# Adobe Flash CC: Error opening URL...swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, runtime-error, flash-cc

I have been creating a simple AS3 file within Flash to create a mockup. However today, I have got the following error when trying to test the file in the output:

```
**Error opening URL '/:Users:Name:Documents:Work:Projects:Graduate Project:Design:Tablet/Mobile:New Mockup:baby.swf'**
```

Now when the file is moved to a slightly different location within Documents (/:Users:Name:Documents) the file loads fine.

Anyone know of a reason this might be happening? There has been a recent update, maybe this could have affected it?

Comment: What is the URL of the path when it works? How are you referencing this file in your code? Are you using hard-coded URLs?

Comment: Are you testing using different login accounts? Also try hard-coding the user name in the path...

Comment: It's fine with other login accounts, but with this one hard coding the path makes no difference. The working URL is '/:Users:Name:Documents' which is referenced using hand-coded URLs in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im using a Mac version of CS6 and I was getting this error. It looks simple - it cannot find the directory.

I was using slash in the directory names like 2/3/4. As soon as I replaced with underscore it was solved...